# Adding RAM to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Which environment variable should I use to add more RAM to Tomcat?

`JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -Xms256m"`

or

`CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -Xms256m"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either will work.  However, from [skill-guru](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/09/23/how-to-increase-heap-size-in-tomcat-6/)...

> Note that CATALINA_OPTS is a better place than JAVA_OPTS. The former
>   is only used when actually starting the Tomcat instance. JAVA_OPTS is
>   also used to start JVMs that only interact with Tomcat (for example
>   the JVM instance that is used to send the shutdown-message to a
>   running Tomcat instance).

Answer (score 1):

CATALINA_OPTS is used to control Tomcat environment options, whereas JAVA_OPTS controls the environment options at a higher level ie. for any Java library.

Windows: `set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms(min heap)m -Xmx(max heap)m`

Linux: `export CATALINA_OPTS=”-Xms(min heap)m -Xmx(max heap)m”`

Answer (score 1):

When you'll use CATALINA_OPTS then it's clear that this option is related to Tomcat server. Also when you'll use JAVA_OPTS then any other application could use this settings, and that isn't something that you probably intentionally want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_OPTS. You are providing options to the java command, not the catalina one (which is a shell script).

Comment: Nope - see Andrew Rose's quote for the reason to use CATALINA_OPTS